# Exporting toon shader maya

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, maya

As a project for a little game jam we are doing we have made maya models for a unity project but the problem is that we can not export the toon shader from maya. We tried exporting fbx, acsii, obj and even trying to apply it separately as a material and nothing has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can't export shaders to Unity

You have to create/buy a toon shader for Unity and apply it to your imported model, as the systems used by Maya and Unity are not the same, compatible, or even 1:1 translatable.

1. because Maya doesn't include any of the shader *code* when you export (to any format)
2. even if it did, Unity wouldn't know what to do with it
3. no other 3D modeling software will do this either, for the same reasons, because shaders are not data.